# How hard would it be to turn our binary-based microprocessors into trinary?

Tags: compression, cpu, cpu-architecture, ternary

How hard would it be to turn our binary-based microprocessors into trinary, where we could have three options, 0 1 and something else, maybe 2? The specific reason I was wondering is for compression. What you could do is when compressing any file, you'd use the third option (2) to indicate a substitution for any number of repeating values of 0 or 1. You'd then include whatever sequence you substitute with 2 at the beginning of your file in the file encoding (maybe a wrapper). So if you had the following binary where the most common sequence was `0000`

```
0110000110111111111000001011011010000001100001
```

you could replace `0000` with 2 each time in the binary to make it trinary, like this

```
0112110111111111201011011012001121
```

then add the sequence `0000` arbitrarily encoded at the front. This could reduce the size of most files significantly up front, and even then it doesn't rule out other forms of compression.

It seems like adding a third option specifically for compression or any other function could be really useful, but I assume it'd be pretty hard to redesign microprocessors to have this ability. Does anyone know if this has been seriously attempted recently?

Comment: The ternary thing has been [done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer).  See [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer)

Comment: If compression is the motivation, you might look into converting storage and networking  before converting microprocessors, because if you can't store it or share it then it isn't that useful.

Comment: Your suggested run-length compression of 0's and 1's using 2's is an extremely poor use of the information capacity of a ternary system. Instead you would simply use all possible values. Eight ternary digits is the equivalent of 12.68 binary bits, and would be used as such.

Comment: As Mark says, two trits hold the same amount of information as three bits, and in bulk (e.g. a whole sector of a disk or a packet on a wire or radio) it's up to you how you encode information into physical signals / states.  TLC flash already uses 3 levels per cell, storing trits (which get en/decoded 2:3 to bits for store / load).  [QAM radio protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) encode multiple bits per symbol, although that naturally uses powers of 2.  IDK if powers of 3 would be obviously worse.

Comment: A 3-state flip-flop or SRAM cell for use inside a ternary CPU would need more transistors than one that only held a single binary bit, but as Erik said it's been tried.  Efficient CMOS logic is naturally binary on/off; a middle voltage level is fundamentally not compatible with the most efficient way we know to build logic circuits.  Hardware that can naturally do positive / negative / zero could make it practically viable, as noted in the Wiki page Erik linked, e.g. two orthogonal polarizations of light, vs. dark.